# grid CellEditing plugin

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kyousuke_rin/fBAgE/)

Please run the demo and double click the son column.
When the cell is edit state, it show [Object Object]. It is not what I want.
When exit edit it resume correctly in IE but wrrong in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using it correctly, when you declared the grid column you are essentially defining an object by

```
{name: "S1"},{name: "S2"},
```

You should either call on a different function to show a modal/window to edit the values in that cell.

Comment: Orginally I didn't want to edit value in cell, so you can see I have set the readOnly:true attribute. It can't select the text in grid with extjs4. I just want to use CellEditing plugin to be able to select the text in grid.

Comment: Isn't it better just to do it directly? http://jsfiddle.net/Zvd8y/ Or are you planning to retrieve the set of sons as an object from the db ?

Comment: The son must be an object because I need its id to do something and its name to display in grid.